# Marker is unknown in angular2-google-maps

Tags: angular2-google-maps

I am declaring a array for markers but it is not available .

error is "Cannot find name 'marker'."

[image]

What might be the issue?

Comment: may you are missing typing for it. you can declar any as a work around an oroceed

Comment: Thanks it worked